# SharePoint 2010 new SPSite throwing FileNotFoundException

Tags: sharepoint

here's my code

```
SPSite spsite = new SPSite(@"http://sharepoint-url/");
```

The URL is right, I can run it in the browser. The problem is, my user does not have Admin rights. Is there a way to say the console, he should run this command as a different user? (I have an Admin Account).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect *remotely* to a SharePoint machine using *server-side object model*, i.e. the `SPSite` class (and others). This is not a supported scenario in SharePoint *by design*.

Both in 2010 and in 2013 there a possibility to use [*client-side object model*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/csom/info), but the key question here is if it could satisfy your needs. In 2010 it's rather limited.

Comment: Every technology has its pros and cons. However, without understanding its philosophy and architecture it's short-sighted to claim it's “unacceptable” based on a specific API aspect. Generally, by having an arbitrary DLL that provides some .NET API it would be foolish to expect it can somehow automagically provide access to a remote system without any remote APIs (be in WCF, Remoting, or whatever else) in between.

Comment: That's true, I just went "full retard" by trying to use LINQ to SP and then finding out that it only works on the server :(

Comment: Generally, I would recommend designing a server-side feature to encapsulate complex SharePoint operations, and publish a custom WCF API to any client apps you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you need to run with elevated permissions:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    // Your Code Here
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't need elevated rights since I'm administrator on my local machine, I need to run as a different user which is admin on the machine I try to connect to.

Comment: Ok sorry I misunderstood you